# Why does \@ifnextchar not work within tables (tabular)?

Tags: tables, sourcecode, booktabs

Why does `\@ifnextchar\end{tabular}{}{\midrule}` not work while `\midrule` works fine within tables?

I am interested especially in a canonical answer to satisfy my curiosity.

However, my intention was to write code that automatically eliminates the `\hline` after the last row. I am open to suggestions.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{booktabs}% \midrule

\catcode`@=11 % or \makeatletter to change category code of @ to 11 and temporarily to access kernel macro \@tabularcr
\let \clone@tabularcr \@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\clone@tabularcr \midrule}% first version
%\def\@tabularcr{\clone@tabularcr \@ifnextchar\end{tabular}{}{}}% <-- this line works, injecting no tokens
%\def\@tabularcr{\clone@tabularcr \@ifnextchar\end{tabular}{}{\midrule}}% <-- this does not work, injecting hopefully just a \midrule as in first version
\catcode`@=12 % or \makeatother to restore category code of @ to 12

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Meaning & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\\ & col2 & col3 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To begin with, you're saying that if the next token is `\end`, then `{tabular}` should be used, otherwise nothing. But it's not the only problem.

Comment: Perhaps `\let\cloneendtabular\endtabular
\def\endtabular{\midrule\cloneendtabular}` would accomplish your goal instead.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Nice suggestion. I will consider it, although I am not sure I want to take that route for compatibility reasons. It depends on the document I suppose.

Comment: @egreg I was thinking of macros being one token when I typed `\end{tabular}`, but of course `\end` is the macro! `\endtabular` is what I should have written.

Comment: @macmadness86 There's no expansion done by `\@ifnextchar` so `\endtabular` would not be seen at all. However, the main problem is that you're starting a cell, because `\@ifnextchar` does assignments, so it is too late for adding `\midrule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign
```

which isn't that related to `\@ifnextchar` you get the same from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{booktabs}% \midrule

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Meaning & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\\ & col2 & col3 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\relax\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`\midrule` like `\hline` and several other table commands must be the first thing in the row (after expansion) as it uses the `\noalign` primitive.

So any non-expandable token will generate an error, `\@ifnextchar` involves several `\def` assignments internally while making the tests.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. When `\@ithnextchar`  is expanded, some `\def`s (non-expandable) are put before `\noalign` and trigger an error. My idea then would be to use `TeX` or `TeX` wrapped in a LaTeX macro to check for `\endtabular` (or whatever the closing token is).  e.g. `\futurelet` or something. I rarely need to do that, so I'd have to do some self-study. https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-3/tb22bechtolsheim.pdf

Comment: @macmadness86 `\futurelet` is non expandable so you can't use that (unless you hide it in `\noalign`)